# Setting up new router for optimal performance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I bought a new [D-Link N300](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-615-wireless-n-300-router) Router today to replace my old G router.

I've two computers at home:

- 1 Desktop (can plug directly to the router OR use a USB Wifi stick (Wireless G) to connect the router)
- 1 Laptop (Use WIreless N radio signal to connect to the router)

For optimal range/speed for my LAPTOP, should I plug my desktop directly to the router or use the USB Wifi (Wireless G Radio signal) for the desktop computer? Are there any differences?

Comment: USB can suck sometimes, I havent used USB wifi in years because the speed was much to slow. I'd rather get a PCI card for it. On a brand new router you will not see much difference in performance if your on a home connection

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend using a wired connection if possible. It avoids any possible glitches in the WiFi signal. In your case, it also avoids having to buy a USB WiFi stick and possible problems with its software.

With a laptop, WiFi is OK because it adds the benefit that you can move around with it, but that is not an option for the desktop.